# Bootstrap js not loading on Live server

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched the other questions but I do not get anything that really solves my problem. I downloaded a template that I want to use as a small portfolio for myself. On my local server everything works fine. But when I upload it to a live server something goes wrong. I believe the problem is with the Bootstrap.js or bootstrap-theme.css

Some functions are not running and dont display at all. Such as the loading bar when you open the site, backgrounds, some images and arrows.

I have done the following.

Checked all the paths to make sure they are correct. 
Made sure that it is not a cache issue.
Tried to run it in private view (still the same problem)
Checked the firefox error log but all scripts seem to load.

Here is the template demo - http://designova.net/presence/index01.html

Here is my live version - codethis.co.za

Here is the code in the head and the js at the bottom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Code This -  Beautiful Website Design and More</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.codethis.co.za/bootstrap/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.codethis.co.za/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" ></script>
<script src="http://www.codethis.co.za/javascripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Standard Favicon--> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon/favicon.ico">

<!-- Standard iPhone Touch Icon--> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/touchicons/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed" />
<!-- Retina iPhone Touch Icon--> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="assets/touchicons/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed" />
<!-- Standard iPad Touch Icon--> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="assets/touchicons/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed" />
<!-- Retina iPad Touch Icon--> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="assets/touchicons/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed" />

<!-- Bootstrap CSS Files -->
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom Fonts Setup via Font-face CSS3 -->
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/fonts/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- CSS files for plugins -->
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/stylesheets/pace.preloader.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/stylesheets/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/stylesheets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/stylesheets/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/stylesheets/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" > 
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/stylesheets/jquery.tweet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/stylesheets/foliohover.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/stylesheets/fancymenu.css"  rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/stylesheets/intro.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.codethis.co.za/stylesheets/pricing.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Main Template Styles -->
<link href="stylesheets/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Main Template Responsive Styles -->
<link href="stylesheets/main-responsive.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Main Template Retina Optimizaton Rules -->
<link href="stylesheets/main-retina.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- LESS stylesheet for managing color presets -->

<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- LESS JS engine-->
<script src="http://www.codethis.co.za/less/less-1.5.0.min.js" type="text/css"></script>
<script src="http://www.codethis.co.za/javascripts/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

 <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="bootstrap/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="bootstrap/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<style>
    .full-height{
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

and at the bottom

```
<!-- JS Plugins -->
<script src="javascripts/pace.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/retina.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/device.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/okvideo.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.mixitup.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/flexslider.js" ></script> 

<script src="javascripts/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script> 
<script src="javascripts/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/form-validation.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/classie.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/fancymenu-rollin.js"></script>
<!-- Scroll Animations Setup -->
<script src="javascripts/wow.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/animations-init.js"></script>
<!-- Custom Scripts Setup -->
<script src="javascripts/carousel-init.js" ></script> 
<script src="javascripts/portfolio.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/intro.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
```

Please could someone help me with what is going on here

Comment: i noticed you're loading jquery twice .. remove <script src="http://www.codethis.co.za/bootstrap/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: You load main.js before you load jQuery. That's also a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your page is riddled with 404 errors, which means either (1) your paths are not correct, or (2) the files do not exist on the server.

[image: 404 errors in Chrome console]

Something to look at would be whether you are using relative paths or absolute paths for your JS, CSS, and image assets. Remember:

- paths that start with a `/` will resolve to `http://codethis.co.za/<path>`
- paths that do not start with a `/` will resolve relative to whatever the current path is

Perhaps you are missing a subfolder in your paths?

Comment: Some of the other errors, I suspect, will be resolved once your paths are correct (e.g., `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` will go away once jQuery loads properly).

Comment: Thank you. I have checked all the paths and they seem to be fine. All my folders and their sub folders are there as well. I made the following changes.

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.codethis.co.za/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" ></script>
<script src="http://www.codethis.co.za/javascripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Removed the jquery line

I also added http://www.codethis.co.za to every path to make sure they are correct. Still have the same problem though

Comment: I just realized that some of the requests are looking for assets on the `www` subdomain, and your server is not configured to allow cross-origin requests (i.e., from `codethis.co.za` to `www.codethis.co.za`). You could either configure your server to allow these cross-origin requests, or you could set up a permanent redirect from one to the other. You'll notice that many of the errors go away when visiting `http://www.codethis.co.za/`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you seem to have a problem loading some of your fonts (cross-origin) It should not be linked with your problem, but you should fix it.

You also have a :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

which could be relative to something with your JQuery, and this could explain a lot if you're using it heavily.

From what I see in network I don't have any missing images.

Thibaut

Comment: Okay I have fixed the errors. But I am still stuck with the same problem. Any other ideas?